# I can't access to Recovery Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, recovery

I want to restore my laptop to the point I bought it. After a fresh install, I have a problem with Bluetooth that wasn't before. But I can't access the Recovery even though it is there and I can see it in Disk Management and I did not delete it while fresh installing! After I press <kbd>F9</kbd> and click Troubleshooting there is no option as MyAsus as there was before! How can I restore it?

Comment: Did the fresh install delete the ASUS recovery partition?  Get an ASUS Recovery USB and reimage the laptop with the ASUS recovery and then "MyAsus" should return.

Comment: No I can still see it in Disk Management and also in the Windows Disk Installation's disk management. It simply says MyAsus. I did not delete 3 partition for it but when I press F9 I can't see MyAsus at all before fresh install it was there.

Comment: Try this: Logout, press and hold the shift key down, select reboot on the login page. Keep holding the shift key depressed. You'll enter the Windows recovery tools. Maybe you can find something useful there.

Answer (score -1):

Windows buries these things. On the Troubleshoot menu, you typically need to look for "Advanced Options" and then look for the ASUS options. If it's still not there, then make a list of what is there and edit your question.